# What's the address of core whitelist contract?

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm trying to check if a given address is a potential validator on Near.

I understand that there is core whitelist contract that exposes a "isWhitelisted" method but I'm not sure how I can find it's address https://github.com/near/core-contracts/tree/master/whitelist

Answer (score 0):

mainnet: lockup-whitelist.near

testnet: whitelist.f863973.m0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).